# How to make 802.11ad wireless work using wil6210 driver

Tags: drivers, wireless, atheros, firmware

I have a laptop with 802.11ad hardware (Wilocity wil6200 802.11ad wireless network adapter). I have also installed Ubuntu 16.0.4 LTS version on it. It has driver wil6210 designed to manage the hardware. I think the firmware loads successfully each time. I have a snapshot of the `syslog` here:

[image: <code>syslog</code> snapshot for firmware load]

But in the network connections section 802.11ad interface (Wilocity) is inactive and it does not connect to the router with SSID `TP-LINK_8FEC_60G`. 
Here is another snapshot of the situation:

[image: Network connections image]

I ran `dmesg` before and after trying to connect to router. The difference is in the following image:

[image: <code>dmesg</code> difference before and after trying to connect]

`wlp2s0` is the interface for `Wilocity wil6200`.

What can I do to fix the problem?

```
driver=wil6210 
driverversion=4.13.0-37-generic 
firmware=4.1.0.55
```

**Update:**

The result of `dmesg | grep wlp2s0` comes in this figure:

[image: <code>dmesg | grep wlp2s0</code>]

The result of `sudo dpkg -s wpasupplicant` is in the following image:

[image: <code>sudo dpkg -s wpasupplicant</code>]

Comment: How and why do you have two network adapters in your laptop and why do you want to connect both? Do you love trouble? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: The two adaptors work in different frequencies. Wilocity works in 60GHz and the other one works in 2.4GHz. The Qualcomm chipsets make this possible. I want this to work for a research project. This hybrid system is not that uncommon for communication as each band has its own pros and cons. And thanks!

Comment: Oh! You *do* love trouble! May we also see: `dmesg | grep wlp2s0` Let's see if it tries to connect and what's going wrong.

Comment: Also: `sudo dpkg -s wpa_supplicant`

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and apply code formatting (https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code)

Comment: I did resolve the problem. All I had to do was to disable encryption on my router for its 11ad interface.